# Convergence of a series in a Hilbert space H.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I was trying to prove a theorem which stated:
Let $\{x_k\}$ be an orthogonal system in a Hilbert space $H$,  then the following are equivalent:
1)$\sum_{k}x_k$ is convergent.
2)$\sum_{k}||x_k||^2$ is convergent.
3)$\sum_{k}x_k$ is unconditionally convergent. i.e. it is absolutely convergent.
I was able to show the equivalence between statement 1 and 2. but i just can't seem to see why ($2\Rightarrow3$). I have to show $\sum_{k}||x_k||^2$ is convergent $\Rightarrow$ $\sum_k||x_k||$ is convergent. i tried to check with basic comparison test, but we can't imply in general that $||x_k||^2 \le ||x_k||$. can anyone help me out?

Comment: The implication $\sum\|x_k\|^2<\infty\implies \sum\|x_k\|<\infty $ is false. For example let $x_k={1\over k}e_k$ where $e_k$ form an infinite orthonormal system. Besides "unconditionally" means that you may change the order of terms in $\sum x_k.$ It is not equivalent to the absolute convergence in case the space has infinite dimension.

Comment: can you please provide an example how unconditional convergence is different from absolute convergence in an Infinite dimensional space? also how do i proceed in my proof?

Comment: The  series $\sum {e_k\over k}$ is convergent uncoditionally but not absolutely.